# Converting a json response to my requirement

Tags: javascript, json

I have received a JSON response like

```
            [
             {"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2017", "month":"4", "amount":"1000"},
             {"no":002, "location": "Italy", "year":"2017", "month":"3", "amount":"8000"},
             {"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "month":"2", "amount":"9000"},
             {"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "month":"11","amount":"12000"}
            ];
```

I need to make it

```
            [
             {"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "amount2":"9000", "amount11":"12000"},
             {"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2017", "amount4":"1000"},
             {"no":002, "location": "Italy", "year":"2017", "amount3":"8000"}
            ];
```

that is based on the no converting multiple records to one with amounts specific to months and common info ie location but same no should have different records corresponding to the year.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show us your existing code?

Comment: i have tried to push the values to new json but do not know to convert the fields month=2 and amount to amount2

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your example isn't even complete, since the second row is unchanged.....

Comment: ty for trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated es5 code to match your latest edit of the question:
(I'm still not sure I understand what you want from `no` so for now I leave it as `number` which it is in input (not in quotes)

```js
var input = [
{"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2017", "month":"4", "amount":"1000"},
{"no":002, "location": "Italy", "year":"2017", "month":"3", "amount":"8000"},
{"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "month":"2", "amount":"9000"},
{"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "month":"11","amount":"12000"}
];

/*
[
{"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2016", "amount2":"9000", "amount11":"12000"},
{"no":001, "location": "England", "year":"2017", "amount4":"1000"},
{"no":002, "location": "Italy", "year":"2017", "amount3":"8000"}
];
*/

var output = input.reduce( function(result, cur) {
  var ref = result.find( function(row) {
   return row.no === cur.no && row.location === cur.location && cur.year === row.year }
  );
  if (ref) {
   ref["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
  } else {
   var newRow = { "no": cur.no, "location": cur.location, "year": cur.year };
    newRow["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
    result.push(newRow);
  }
  return result;
},[])

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I assumed I cannot change the input (because it comes from some external service and not your code). I just saw your suggested edit, and if you in fact can affect input, then you will get a string output of `no` if you just surround it in quotes, just like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

General advice: Collect the information by ID in another datastructure.  I suppose this is an [Accumulator Pattern](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Iteration/TheAccumulatorPattern.html).

```
var rows = [
    {"no":"001","month":"4","amount":"1000"},
    {"no":"002","month":"3","amount":"8000"},
    {"no":"001","month":"2","amount":"9000"},
    {"no":"001","month":"11","amount":"12000"}
];
var results = [];

var idToResultsObject = {};

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var id = row['no'];
    if (typeof idToResultsObject[id] == 'undefined')
        idToResultsObject[id] = { 'no' : id };
    idToResultsObject[id]['location'] = row['location'];
    idToResultsObject[id]['amount' + row['month']] = row['amount'];
}

for (var id in idToResultsObject) {
    results.push(idToResultsObject[id]);
}

console.log(results);
```

Surely there is a nicer way to store this.

Comment: Please help in getting two records based on year

Comment: We already have an object that is organized per ID ie `idToResultsObject` , how could we make an object that is organized per ID, per year?   Can you make a guess at what the solution would be?  What would the resulting data structure look like?

Comment: idToResultsObject[id]['location'] = row['location']; idToResultsObject[id]['finYr'] = row['finYr']; alert("changing: "+idToResultsObject[id]['finYr']); idToResultsObject[id]['amount' + row['month']] = row['amount']; since i got the id as unique and its easy to retrieve amount from that but for it must be done on basic of year the current code adds the last year for tht id to JSON and amounts for all years together

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it's really a bad way to design those objects. But this code does what you want (es6 syntax):

```js
var input = [
    {"no":001,"month":"4","amount":"1000"},
    {"no":002,"month":"3","amount":"8000"},
    {"no":001,"month":"2","amount":"9000"},
    {"no":001,"month":"11","amount":"12000"}
];

/*
[
    {"no":001, "amount2":"9000", "amount4":"1000", "amount11":"12000"},
    {"no":002, "amount3":"8000"}
];
*/

var output = input.reduce( (result, cur) => {
  var ref = result.find( row => row.no === cur.no);
  if (ref) {
   ref["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
  } else {
   var newRow = { "no": cur.no };
    newRow["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
    result.push(newRow);
  }
  return result;
},[])

console.log(output);
```

Comment: my js not supporting this =>

Answer (score 0):

es5 syntax

```js
var input = [
    {"no":001,"month":"4","amount":"1000"},
    {"no":002,"month":"3","amount":"8000"},
    {"no":001,"month":"2","amount":"9000"},
    {"no":001,"month":"11","amount":"12000"}
];

/*
[
    {"no":001, "amount2":"9000", "amount4":"1000", "amount11":"12000"},
    {"no":002, "amount3":"8000"}
];
*/

var output = input.reduce( function(result, cur) {
  var ref = result.find( function(row) { return row.no === cur.no });
  if (ref) {
   ref["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
  } else {
   var newRow = { "no": cur.no };
    newRow["amount"+cur.month] = cur.amount;
    result.push(newRow);
  }
  return result;
},[])

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @DripuraSundari, in your example, `no` is not a string, it's just badly typed number (with leading zeros). I see you changed your Q in the meantime and added year, so above code was for original example. Either way, your original core of the problem as you said was: "i have tried to push the values to new json but do not know to convert the fields month=2 and amount to amount2". That part is solved and you have more than enough code in all the answers above to compile what you need, or to listen to advice (if possible) and change output object to something better.